# React Typescript event type for both interfaces MouseEvent and TouchEvent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I am trying to write a function to handle both `mouse` and `touch` events. By combining both interfaces `React.TouchEvent` and `React.MouseEvent`,
like:

```
onStart = (event: React.TouchEvent | React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.persist();
    console.log('event ', event);
    if (event.touches) {
        console.log(event.touches);
    }
    if (event.screenX) {
        console.log(event.screenX);
    }
};
```

The logs give me the expected output and I don't get any console error, it runs as it I expected. But I get errors on my editor:

> Error:(94, 22) TS2339: Property 'screenX' does not exist on type
>   'MouseEvent | TouchEvent'.   Property
>   'screenX' does not exist on type 'TouchEvent'.

and

> Error:(90, 13) TS2339: Property 'touches' does not exist on type
>   'MouseEvent | TouchEvent'.   Property
>   'touches' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'.

How can I use both intefaces `React.TouchEvent` and `React.MouseEvent` without all this errors?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By checking for `instanceof TouchEvent` and `instanceof MouseEvent` in the condition and using the `nativeEvent` property inside `event`, it is possible to access each individual interface with no errors.

```
onStart = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.persist();
    console.log('event ', event);
    if (event.nativeEvent instanceof TouchEvent) {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.touches);
    }

    if (event.nativeEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.screenX);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I will use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of TypeScript. Code is more readable.

E.g.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function isTouchEvent(e: React.TouchEvent | React.MouseEvent): e is React.TouchEvent {
  return e && 'touches' in e;
}

function isMouseEvent(e: React.TouchEvent | React.MouseEvent): e is React.MouseEvent {
  return e && 'screenX' in e;
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  onStart = (event: React.TouchEvent | React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.persist();
    if (isTouchEvent(event)) {
      console.log(event.touches);
    }
    if (isMouseEvent(event)) {
      console.log(event.screenX);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div>my component</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the benefit of this solution vs the previous one which is simpler? what are you gaining with all this extra code, that the previous can't handle? (curious question)

Comment: There are 2 benefits:

1. Predicates can be reused in other handlers
2. Code is more clear without extra `.nativeEvent` path